# Annotate a footnote in a ggvis chart?

Tags: r, ggvis

I'd like to add something like a footnote to a ggvis chart. I don't think there is an annotate functionality in ggvis. One idea is to use the axis title, but I can't get the text to change lines. Does anyone have a suggestion?

below is a mre.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))
ggvis(df, x=~x, y=~y) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    add_axis("x", orient = "bottom", title = "X") %>%
    add_axis("x", orient = "bottom", grid=F, ticks = 0, title = "footnote here?
            \n line 1 \n line2 \n line 3", title_offset= 60,
             properties = axis_props(
                 ticks = list(stroke= NULL),
                 axis = list(stroke = NULL),
                 labels = list(fontSize = 0),
                 title=list(fontSize=14) ) ) # this creates one line title
```

Comment: I think you are thinking along the right lines.  Unfortunately line breaks don't work at this time - see [this open issue](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/359)